pythonic way of using @property
I am trying to wrap my head around the different ways of using getters and setters through @property. I have read docs, blogs and posts here, but can't find a convention. There might not be one, but I assume some approaches are more suited for some applications and some are maybe more pythonic?
Any best practices?
Example 1 (I assume it is redundant to do the check for a<0 in setter and init?):
class ExponentialDecay:

    def __init__(self, a: float) -> None:
        if a < 0:
            raise ValueError("Decay constant cannot be negative.")
        self._a = a

    @property
    def decay(self) -> float:
        return self._a
    
    @decay.setter
    def decay(self, value: float) -> None:
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("Decay constant cannot be negative.")
        self._a = value

Example 2 (use setter in init):
class ExponentialDecay:

    def __init__(self, a: float) -> None:
        self.decay = a

    @property
    def decay(self) -> float:
        return self._a
    
    @decay.setter
    def decay(self, value: float) -> None:
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("Decay constant cannot be negative.")
        self._a = value

Example 3:
Same code, but using name mangling in init or in the setter (self.__decay).
Trying to learn more, not stuck on a problem per se.

Your first example repeats the same code in two different places, better avoid that. Note that name mangling is rather unrelated to that question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name about it.

Thanks, yes. I agree that the first approach is rather redundant, but I see so many examples in articles where you have example 1, but without the first if condition. And I often wonder why they chose to check in the setter but not in init? In a lot of those examples they can end up having the wrong initial condition because they don't call the setter or have an if check (?), eg neg age by accident. Any ideas why?
Any considerations when calling the settes under init in example 2?

I like to think of _a as an implementation detail of the property instance decay that ExponentialDecay agrees to "host", but otherwise does not touch. (Sort of like a bank deposit box: your valuables are stored at the bank, but the bank has no right to use your valuables.)

Typically the hidden attribute corresponding to the property will have a similar name, e.g. self._decay. Using a meaningless and totally unrelated name like a makes the code harder to understand.

To some extent, _a is an implementation detail of the property, not ExponentialDecay, and so ExponentialDecay should not use it directly, only "agree" to store it for the property to use. So Example 2 is "correct": ExponentialDecay.__init__ should let decay check and store the value of a itself.
(The name _a and its existence, though, are considered part of the public interface of the property. Name-mangling would prevent subclasses of ExpoentialDecay from overwriting it, but not from ExponentialDecay itself from doing so. So we can thankfully dismiss Example 3 as a necessary option.)

It's worth noting that neither the getter or setter are methods of ExponentialDecay, but simply functions stored by the property object which the property calls using an ExponentialDecay instance as an explicit argument. For example,
self.decay = a

is implemented with
type(self).decay.__set__(self, a)

which itself is implemented by
type(self).decay.fset(self, a)

